# Center align image <img> in hyperlink <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have an image coded like so:

```
<img src="assets/img/facebookImage.png">
```

I also have an `<a>` hyperlink tag wrapped around the `<img>` tag, that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="width: 80%">
```

The image is not centered in the hyperlink box.

[image]

How can I align the facebook icon image in the hyperlink box? Here is the full code section for context:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" style="width: 80%">
  <img src="assets/img/facebookImage.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Try setting the `<img />` to `display: block;`.

Comment: Hey BenM, no luck unforunately :(

Comment: align:middle is not a valid property.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I've removed it

Comment: can you provide us fiddle link to understand better?

Comment: Are you sure the image is not designed to have the Facebook `f` off-center?

Comment: 100% sure Quantastical

Comment: @Rohit csstudio.com.au is the live link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove max-width: none; from img, remove left and right padding from a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, make them display block, both elements, nest them in the html and set img margin to 0 auto.

```
a {
display:block;
border: 1px blue solid;
width:100px; height:100px;
padding:10px;
}
img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;}
```

Play around and set different width to the img or the link and it will always be centered.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/RRWzdr

Answer (score 0):

Set a width and height on img tag to match the size link box you need. Setting this on your site's img tag centers the image in the link box:

```
width: 21px;
height: 20px;
```

[image]